# How to call a variable between double qoutes in bash?

Tags: bash, variables

I'm trying to execute this command in a script:

```
axel "$1"
```

Where "$1" is a URL sent to this command in a script by the firefox plugin FlashGot. However,the URL is long and it keeps cutting it off short. The only way to overcome this is to enclose the URL in single or double quotes...eg. "http://...."

Thanks, in advance.

EDIT:
Ok, so an example of the URL is http://audio-sjl-t1-2.pandora.com/access/Letting%20Go%20-%20Isaac%20Shepard%2Emp4a?version=4&lid=290476474&token=Z6TTYtio6FYbhzesbxzPyWA%2F%2Bfa2uT5atbV8L0QF%2FMubHshmLJ1hgkN6B8SMZe74V8Q1feGMNmkmyTJO343qYkQ3aklQVKo4mDE2VVl1nkYk05gu0%2BBfP3WtxTCrn8r0gz0wwDgMfzQd68fBcmOTKtB%2FjR2kqVs9ZY7tZQUuabjGcP84ws%2BuIsuTqkKkHyrWaaLkGhk71GoPng2IMrm0L%2B6MeyHu6bvWn%2FoqNhXNerpFLpRZqXZ8JrX9uKVkDmkeQxUVV5%2F8y8uv2yYpG3P5tx1mfAY6U7ZteDLCfCT4JQWzlZscpl7GmtW4gf64KBExGA98xucIp%2Bt1x%2Bjru2Jt%2F7PVeeKWGv2en0%2Fetf1CQWjVUbDoWy4q9cEnYOc7rkpX

Well, it keeps cutting it off at

```
http://audio-sjl-t1-2.pandora.com/access/Letting%20Go%20-%20Isaac%20Shepard%2Emp4a?version=4
```

and that is all is getting sent to axel.

I added an echo command in the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/caleb/Desktop
echo "$1"
axel "$1"
```

I can see the debug of a script by sending a URL to it through the terminal:

```
./axel.sh <URL>
```

The only error message I see is because of the shortened URL.

Here's the output of the script above:

```
http://audio-sjl-t1-2.pandora.com/access/Letting%20Go%20-%20Isaac%20Shepard%2Emp4a?version=4
Initializing download: http://audio-sjl-t1-2.pandora.com/access/Letting%20Go%20-%20Isaac%20Shepard%2Emp4a?version=4
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

Comment: How long is 'really long'? 256 bytes? 1 KiB? 4 KiB? 16 KiB? 64 KiB? Bigger?  You'll eventually run into an argument length limit (128 KiB to 512 KiB) on most machines, but you should be dealing with URLs that are as big as that (it would be an abuse of a GET URL).

Comment: The real issue may be how you *set* the value of `$1`, rather than how you access its value.

Answer (score 1):

`axel "$1"` should work and I'm not surprised `axel ""$1""` doesn't work because that's equivalent to `axel $1`.

To debug this we'll need an error message or something, because saying "it doesn't work" doesn't help at all.

You say the script is called from Firefox. I'm not sure if you can easily see the error message, maybe you can't. I have an idea for that. Let's call your script `script.sh`. Create a wrapper script `script-wrapper.sh` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
log=/tmp/script.log
for arg; do
    echo arg="'$arg'" | tee $log
done
/path/to/script.sh >>$log 2>&1
```

Make this script executable, trigger it from Firefox, and then look at the log, which will include both the output and error output of your original script. If you still can't figure out what is wrong, then edit your question, and paste in the content of `/tmp/script.log` so we can debug.

**UPDATE**

Based on your update, it looks like the script does not receive the URL correctly. In particular, it looks like the URL is not quoted properly when you pass it to the script. It's not surprising that the cut-off happens right in front of a `&` character, as that means something to the shell. You should call your script like this:

```
./axel.sh "http://....?version=4&lid=..."
```

But this is not happening, it looks it's getting called without the double-quotes, which will result in the behavior you're observing.

Answer (score 0):

Just using

```
#!/bin/sh
axel "$1"
```

**will** work.  If it isn't, you're going to need to give a lot more information...